# Prove $f(z)=(z-1)^a(z+1)^b$ has a branch in $\mathbb{C}\backslash[-1,1]$ iff $a+b\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove $f(z)=(z-1)^a(z+1)^b$ has a branch in $\mathbb{C}\backslash[-1,1]$ iff $a+b\in\mathbb{Z}$
I've tried the following
Assuming that we have a branch for $f$
$f(z)=(z-1)^{a+b}(\frac{z+1}{z-1})^{b}=(z-1)^{a+b}(1+\frac{2}{z-1})^b$, i know that if $z\notin[-1,1]$ then $(1+\frac{2}{z-1})\notin (-\infty,0]$ and we can take a branch for this and then we have a branch for$(1+\frac{2}{z-1})^b$ now i got stuck on how to show that $a+b\in\mathbb{Z}$.
I thought maybe setting $e^{(a+b)log(z-1)}=w$ and we know  that $e^z$ is $2\pi k$ periodical and therfore $(a+b)\in\mathbb{Z}$